# How to convert resultset data into my object. Below is the format of data

Tags: java, mysql, spring

My data is like this return in resultset

```
[[{hostItemId=44, userId=1, title=This is the title 29 for skill(cleaning) for paid items..., description=This is the description 29 for skill ( cleaning) for paid items..., isFree=false, price=42.0, requestCount=2, categoryId=3, attachmentUrl=1478684543988image.jpg, currencySymbol=20B9, hostItemStatus=3, shareType=1}, {hostItemId=24, userId=1, title=This is title 15 for skill (spring chores)..., description=This is the description 15 for skill (spring chores)..., isFree=true, price=null, requestCount=2, categoryId=3, attachmentUrl=1478672337661image.jpg, currencySymbol=null, hostItemStatus=3, shareType=1}]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The Json data you have giving is wrong. It will throw an error. Right syntax for Json data is `var jsondata  = [
  [
    {
      "hostItemId": 44,
      "userId": 1,
      "title": "This is the title 29 for skill(cleaning) for paid items...",
      "description": "This is the description 29 for skill ( cleaning) for paid items...",
      "isFree": false,
      "price": 42,
      "requestCount": 2,
      "categoryId": 3,
      "attachmentUrl": "1478684543988image.jpg",
      "currencySymbol": "20B9",
      "hostItemStatus": 3,
      "shareType": 1
    },
    {
      "hostItemId": 24,
      "userId": 1,
      "title": "This is title 15 for skill (spring chores)...",
      "description": "This is the description 15 for skill (spring chores)...",
      "isFree": true,
      "price": null,
      "requestCount": 2,
      "categoryId": 3,
      "attachmentUrl": "1478672337661image.jpg",
      "currencySymbol": null,
      "hostItemStatus": 3,
      "shareType": 1
    }
  ]
]`

after that you can decode this json string into your object.

```
// Creating a JSONObject from a String 
JSONObject nodeRoot  = new JSONObject(jsondata); 

// Creating a sub-JSONObject from another JSONObject
JSONObject nodeStats = nodeRoot.getJSONObject("stats");
```